# Import products with different currency

Tags: magento-1.9, import, currency, magmi, multicurrency

I'm currently running a Magento store using USD as my default currency.
I want to import products from different providers into my store.
Half of those providers are giving me CAD prices and the other half, USD.

I've created an OpenOffice file for each of those provider for mass importing with Magmi but I can't figure out how to specify the currency.

So I want all those products to be on the same website and everything showing in USD, does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to upload a product in Magento with 2 different currencies for a website view. As far as I can see you have 2 options

- Start a website view for CAD prices (This may not be ideal based or you audience, etc)
- Convert the CAD prices into USD and import them under the `price` field in Magento.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I convert all my prices into USD before importing. But that also means I have to re-import all my new prices when the exchange rate changed.